# Import-CSV returns null

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-4.0, import-csv

I have a CSV file which uses semi-colon delimeters, and is encoded as UTF-8 (no mark).

The following works as expected:

```
$fn = '\\path\to\file.csv'
ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' -InputObject (get-content $fn -Encoding UTF8)
```

But the simpler expression returns null:

```
$fn = '\\path\to\file.csv'
import-csv $fn -Delimiter ';' -Encoding UTF8
```

Has anyone seen this behaviour before / any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the input file's line end character.

Viewing the file in Programmers' Notepad I was able to view the line end markers.

They were carriage returns (i.e. MAC's preference for line endings).

Replacing these with the Windows' style ending, carriage return + line feed, `import-csv` functioned as expected.